# How do I count missing values per variable in PROC SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

I need to check my variables for missing values, and I figured PROC SQL seemed like a decent way of doing things. The code below does not seem to work however, it just outputs the total number of observations in the dataset:

```
PROC SQL; SELECT count(UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers is missing) FROM IBIS3_5;
WHERE Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg=1;
quit;
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: what is the definition of missing?  that UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers is null?

Comment: Missing values are typically coded as '.' in the dataset. I tried writing UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers=. but got the same result

Comment: UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers is null also just generates the total number of rows in the datset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting how many times the result of testing if the variable is missing results in a non-missing value.  Since the result of the test is always going to be either 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE) it is never missing.  So you are doing the same thing as if you did COUNT(*).

So the SQL method is to just use count(UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers) to count the non-missing values.  If you want the number of missing values instead then subtract from the total number of observations.

```
count(*)-count(UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers)
```

But why not use the MISSING() function?

```
PROC SQL; 
   SELECT Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg
        , count(*) as N_observations
        , sum(missing(UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers)) as N_missing
   FROM IBIS3_5
   group by Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg
   ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The nmiss-function seems to do the job:

```
PROC SQL; 
SELECT nmiss(UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers)
FROM IBIS3_5
WHERE Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg=1;
quit;
```